# How to calculate the absolute discounting used in n-gram model?

Tags: statistics, n-gram

May I ask some questions about the implementation of the absolute discounting? Thank you for any help!

My graduation project is about the n-gram language model, and I try the absolute discounting. I refer to the formula on the [page](http://www.speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/manpages/ngram-discount.7.html):

```
  f(a_z)  = (c(a_z) - D) / c(a_)
  p(a_z)  = (c(a_z) > 0) ? f(a_z) : bow(a_) p(_z)
  bow(a_) = (1 - Sum_Z1 f(a_z)) / (1 - Sum_Z1 f(_z))
```

However, the result of back-off weight printed by my program is not the same as the ARPA file generated by ngram-count. I think this is caused by my misunderstanding of the formula. Here is how I understand. Suppose to calculate bow(a,b):

```
  bow(ab) = (1 - Sum_Z1 f(abz)) / (1 - Sum_Z1 f(bz)) = (N(ab) / C(ab)) / (N(b) / C(b))
```

where N(ab) denote the number of unique n-grams like 'abc' and 'abd'.

Am I right? And when it comes to bow(a), how to calculate the denominator since the there is no suffix in 'a'?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is more conceptual and so it's suitable for stats.stackexchange.com. That said, bear in mind that actual implementations very often differ in details, so that the output numbers you get are not exactly the same, even if you are implementing "the same" model.

Comment: @RobertDodier, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the key factor for my own question. That's encourage! Here is the answer:

The formula posted is wrong

```
bow(ab) = (1 - Sum_Z1 f(abz)) / (1 - Sum_Z1 f(bz)) = (N(ab) / C(ab)) / (N(b) / C(b))
```

and the correct one is

```
bow(ab) = (1 - Sum_Z1 f(abz)) / (1 - Sum_Z1 f(bz)) = (N(ab) * D / C(ab)) / (1 - Sum_Z1 f(bz))
```